# Run exe on computer in network through batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have few computers connected to the network and I want to create batch files to automatize the process of working with them. I have already created one used to shutdown computers at once. It is very simple I ll just post it for the sake of argument.

```
@echo off
shutdown -s -m \\Slave1-PC
shutdown -s -m \\Slave2-PC
shutdown -s -m \\Slave3-PC
```

Now I want to execute programs on these machines. So lets say there is "example.exe" file located "\Slave1-PC\d\example.exe"

using

```
 call \\Slave1-PC\\d\\example.exe
```

runs it on my computer through network and i didn't come up with anything else. I dont want to use any psexec if possible. 
Help would be much appreciated.

Peter

Comment: " I dont want to use any psexec if possible."  Why not?

Comment: I didn't want to use external libraries simply because it makes more sense to use existing easy to write "batch language". I wouldn't have to install anything on these computers as well ... In addition, I never worked with psexec, never tried to set it up so I would need to look at it and that costs time.

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* can't use psexec, then you could probably rig something up with [schtasks](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true) (better) or [at](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/at.mspx?mfr=true) (worse).

However, I think you'd probably spend more time trying to get those to do what you want than you'd spend in setting up [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).  Psexec is really quite simple to use and it only needs to be available (as an executable file; no installer needed) on the machine doing the controlling, not on each machine being controlled.

At its simplest, PsExec is very simple:

```
psexec -accepteula \\RemoteMachine Command Arguments
```

Also, Mark Russinovich (PsExec's author) has written [a primer](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/remote-computing/psexec) that "describes how PsExec works and gives tips on how to use it".  Beyond that, "PsExec /?" and [the manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) do provide quite good information.

Comment: Strange, I thought that it would be really simple. Something like ... run_on_network \\Slave1-PC\\d\\example.exe . Since it is not, I have to look at Psexec I guess. I didn't even know that it only has to be on "Master_PC". That makes is simpler. Could you provide the code using psexec ?

Comment: @peter With batch, it isn't that easy. With PowerShell, it is.

Answer (score 1):

`PSEXEC` is very easy and simple to use. You use it basically in the same way you use `CALL` or `START` (except you give it the target computer and a username and password if needed), and is capable of even launching GUI applications, though you won't be able to see or control it.

When used to launch a command-line program with normal `STDIN` / Console input and `STDOUT` and `STDERR` output, the program or batch file will act as if you are simply running it on your own machine.

I was up and using `PSEXEC` to run diagnostics, defrag.exe, anti-virus programs, and for gathering system information in a shop with over 2,000 PC's without more introduction than `PSEXEC /?` within a day.

Run:

```
PSEXEC \\COMPUTER -u Administrator -p password CMD.exe
```

And you've got the same interactive Command Prompt on `COMPUTER` that you'd have if you walked over and typed <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>CMD<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Maybe a little slower, but it's not noticeable unless you're scrolling through a massive amount of text.  Even over 10 Base-T it's not too bad.

As an Network Administrator able to use the same username / password on nearly every computer, I found that all but the most locked down computers, I didn't even need to use a username or password. This...

```
PSEXEC \\COMPUTER CMD
```

...was usually sufficient.

To use your example type:

```
psexec \\Slave1-PC d:\example.exe
```

Or:

```
psexec \\Slave1-PC cmd
d:
example
```

`PSEXEC` will prompt you for a username and password if they are needed.

The first time you connect to a computer you may need to (or get someone else to) allow the connection via a Pop-Up on the remote system.

[Download it Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

[Learn about it Here](http://www.windowsitpro.com/Windows/Article/ArticleID/42919/42919.html)